# Cordova iOS - White screen after click in a input field

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ratchet-2

When I click on a input field (text) and close the keyboard and then change the view (ui-sref), the app shows a white screen. Unfortunately, no error is shown in the console. Error appears on iPhone, tested with iOS 10 - Cordova iOS 4.40 with Go Ratchet CSS Framework.

See http://makeagif.com/i/i3hMtU for Screen-Recording

Thanks for your help!

Edit: In the meantime, I have disabled the ratchet css files, and then it works fine. Because of this, I think it's a ratchet issue. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found the issue at the base.scss file from the ratchet framework in the ".content" class:

-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Changing the property to -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;  as a workaround resolve the white screen problem.